# Define multi-dimensional array via macro with arduino

Tags: arduino

I would like to define a multi-dimensional array via a macro with the Arduino language. I am trying to save sketch/RAM space.

I would like to do something like so:

```c
#define MYARR {{8, 0}, {8, 1}, {8, 2}, {8, 3}, {8, 4}, {8, 5}, {8, 6}}

function_that_uses_array(MYARR);
```

but I just can't seem to get it to work, and get a multitude of errors. I have tried several different ways of defining the array in the macro, but I am admittedly not even sure this is possible to do.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer you may expect but instead of using multi-dimensional array maybe you could use a one-dimensional array mapping multiple dimensions and use setter/getter functions to work with values as explained [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151084/map-a-2d-array-onto-a-1d-array-c) ?

Helper functions are not necessary if you define dimension sizes as global constants to calculate  index value for given dimensions' indexes - you can work with the 1D array directly then.

**EDIT(5/4/15):**

Other thing is I doubt array can be initialized using a pre-processor macro as:

> All arrays consist of contiguous memory locations

([source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm))

For this reason array must be an initialized variable. It can be initialized in different ways - one using data defined in a macro is described in a link in my comment to this answer however a multi-dimensional array can be also initialized directly:

```
 #define MAX_ROWS 3
 #define MAX_COLS 3
 const int a[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = { {1,2,3},
                                     {4,5,6},
                                     {7,8,9}  };
```

Comment: Interesting, though I suppose that still leaves me in a situation where I still can't figure out how to define an array via a macro in the arduino language. Could you be of help with that?

Comment: Have a look at the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784649/initialize-a-2d-array-of-unknown-size-using-macros-in-c You still have to initialize a variable though (int v[][MAXCOLUMNS] = VALUE; in the linked the answer).  Code compiles but I have no chance at the moment to check it with a real AVR.